# Displaying the search results of a web page in VF page

Tags: visualforce

Hi I want to display results from multiple sites in VF page when a user enter a search text.

Consider there a input text field and when a user enters some search text eg : bing. I want to get results from multiple websites like [bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/)
 by searching for the keyword entered ('Bing') and display the results in VF page and when the user hits the listed result it should redirect to the original link.

Comment: First of all you will be required to check if these services you are intending to use offer search APIs. Of course you can create an `iframe` for all but I think these search engines will have no framing policy active. If they offer search API, then you can create a service to callout their APIs, parse the data and display it to a user.

Comment: The sites which i want to show the result from dont offer any api.

Comment: Bloomberg is not the exact site which I am referring thats only an example. There are some other sites which i cant reveal.

Comment: It will be difficult to get the results without an API. You can create an iframe of the site  and query using the search parameters example https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Sfdc however I think most of sites have no framing policy active